# How to call a search block

Tags: 7

I am newbie to drupal i have integrated the [Apache solr search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module and its working fine. I have disabled the drupal's core search.

Now I am creating my own custom module. How can I make the Apache Solr module search functionality work with my custom module? I need sorting and pagination along with search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing in your module?, If you are building a new entity, you would to use hook_apachesolr_field_mappings() http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_field_mappings/7

An example is the implementation in http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_commerce

Regards!

Comment: @Morale Thanks for your answer, in my module i am building a search page that searches result form apache solr, other than the search block other dashboard kind of stuff will go into the module. To achieve the above whether i can simply link to the search which i have implemented earlier with apache solr and code only dashboard related stuff in my module? or i need to build one more search in my module also ?

Comment: @Morale I need some help on how to achieve sorting along with pagination for my apache solr search results.